# CakePHP PaginationRecallComponent, Strict (2048): Declaration of PaginationRecallComponent::initialize()

Tags: cakephp, initialization, components

I have tried to insert PaginationRecallComponent (http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Zaphod/2012/03/27/paginationrecall_for_cakephp_2_x), in

App -> Controller -> Component -> PaginationRecallComponent.php

UserController:
public $components = array('PaginationRecall');

Why I received the following error:

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of PaginationRecallComponent::initialize() should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller) [APP/Controller/Component/PaginationRecallComponent.php, line 46]
Code Context


App::load() - CORE/Cake/Core/App.php, line 567
App::load() - CORE/Cake/Core/App.php, line 567
spl_autoload_call - [internal], line ??
class_exists - [internal], line ??
ComponentCollection::load() - CORE/Cake/Controller/ComponentCollection.php, line 110
ComponentCollection::init() - CORE/Cake/Controller/ComponentCollection.php, line 53
Controller::constructClasses() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 652
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 183
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 97
```

CakePHP 2.4.2

Answer (score 5):

You get this error because the signature of the `initialize` method in the `PaginationRecallComponent` class is different from the one in its parent class.

If you look at the code you will see that in `Cake/Controller/Component.php` the signature is:

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller)
```

whereas in the `PaginationRecallComponent` it is:

```
function initialize(&$controller)
```

In the first case the `$controller` parameter must be an instance of `Controller`, whereas in the second case there is no such constraint. To get rid of the error you simply have to add this constraint to the signature of the `initialize` method of the `PaginationRecallComponent`.

Comment: @AdityaBhatt You have to add `Controller` to the method signature. Or to say it in different words, the first snippet shows how the second snippet must look like.

Comment: To say it on simplest words, you have to replace    function initialize(&$controller) for     public function initialize(Controller $controller)