# Strict (2048): Declaration of EmailComponent::initialize() should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I upgraded my XAMPP version and installed PHP 5.5.9. After upgradetion I am getting this message. I googled it but not able to find clear idea to fix it. I got one link of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186038/cakephp-paginationrecallcomponent-strict-2048-declaration-of-paginationrecal) , they are talking about signature of the initialize method, but didn't get exactly where I need to modify. Please guide me how to fix it.

Thank you in Advance.

**Error:**

Strict (2048): Declaration of EmailComponent::initialize() should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller) [APP\Controller\Component\EmailComponent.php, line 490]
        Code Context
        App::load() - CORE\Cake\Core\App.php, line 562
        App::load() - CORE\Cake\Core\App.php, line 562
        spl_autoload_call - [internal], line ??
        class_exists - [internal], line ??
        ComponentCollection::load() - CORE\Cake\Controller\ComponentCollection.php, line 100
        ComponentCollection::init() - CORE\Cake\Controller\ComponentCollection.php, line 53
        Controller::constructClasses() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 635
        Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 183
        Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 162
        [main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 109

**EmailComponent:**

[image]

Comment: I have checked that link but the problem was like what i have to wrote to fix the issue. But from your answer I got the clear idea.

Comment: It is the *exact same* issue just another component with the exact same solution provided in the answer. Do yourself a favor to become a better developer and start thinking first and not just waiting for people to provide you copy and paste ready code. I hope I could help you at least in a way that made you understanding the underlying problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the error message, it is very clear:

> Strict (2048): Declaration of EmailComponent::initialize() should be
>   compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller)

Your method signature doesn't match. Make them match.

```
function initialize(Controller $controller)
```