# Cakephp 2.6.2 Comment plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, comments

I am currently doing a site on cakephp 2.6.2.
I use a plugin for comments, as follows: [Comment plugin](http://grafikart.github.io/CakePHP-Comment/usage.html).
Everything works fine until I try to add a comment to a post, it then returns the following error:

> Strict (2048): Declaration of Comment::afterSave() should be compatible with Model::afterSave($created, $options = Array)
>   [APP/Plugin/Comment/Model/Comment.php, line 2]

I do not understand why this error is raised and how I can resolve it.

Comment: Have you tried to simply search for the error code on SO or Google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182482/strict-2048-declaration-of-emailcomponentinitialize-should-be-compatible This has been asked a felt amount of at least 1000 times before and I think the error message is *very* clear. Also this plugin has not been maintained for 3 years I wouldn't use it, it is very simple any way.

Comment: thank you burzu for answer. yes i did but i dont understand english well enough. :s i dont realy understand what i have o do

Answer (score 0):

I searched issues already covered but I do not understand what how I should proceed. I try several times but without success: s

I have in comment.php:

```
    public function afterSave($created){
    if ($created) {
        $model = ClassRegistry::init($this->data[$this->alias]['ref']);
        // Manual countercache, it's more flexible, no need to add complex relation on Comment Model
        if($model->hasField('comment_count')){
            $model->id = $this->data[$this->alias]['ref_id'];
            $model->saveField('comment_count',$this->find('count',array(
                'conditions' => array('ref'=>$this->data[$this->alias]['ref'],'ref_id'=>$this->data[$this->alias]['ref_id'])
            )));
        }
        $this->getEventManager()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('Plugin.Comment.add', $this));
    }
}
```

and CommentsController.php:

```
$this->Comment->create($this->request->data, true);
```

the changes I've tried to do:

```
$this->Comment->create($this->request->data, true);
```

to `$this->Comment->create($this->request->data);`
or $this->Comment->create(controller $this->request->data, true);

I'm sorry but i'dont understand what i exactly have to do :s