# Declaration of SeoComponent::initialize() should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller)

Tags: cakephp, seo

Declaration of SeoComponent::initialize() should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller) [APP\Plugin\Seo\Controller\Component\SeoComponent.php, line 106]

please find the error. why show this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182482/strict-2048-declaration-of-emailcomponentinitialize-should-be-compatible

Comment: Just do what the error tells you to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is the older PHP version issue. 
Solution for your problem is find  `SeoComponent` class & find `initialize` method and replace

```
function initialize(Controller $controller)
```

instead

```
function initialize()
```