# CakePHP2: Declaration of ... should be compatible with

Tags: database, cakephp, external

I've imported a CakePHP Website hosted at External Server to my local server...

But it doesn't work and I received several remarks.  It has displayed on screen like

[image]

I think there is a miss of connection with remote server, but I made all of the standard class database comnnection.

When the index page is requested It's prints a lot of errors with component.

Following is the code for database connection:

```
 class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => '186.202.152.111',
            'login' => 'site1386348519',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'database' => 'site1386348519',
            'prefix' => 'tb_',
            'encoding' => 'utf8'           
    );       
 }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you seen here before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182482/strict-2048-declaration-of-emailcomponentinitialize-should-be-compatible..

Comment: @Marcelo C Curia instead of editing the question with a comment like text please edit it in a way it makes clear that the problem is *really* the DB - which clearly is not the case based on the screenshot. At least as far as somebody could tell by the given information. Did you bother to read the linked question and answer and try to fix your notices and see if it works? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, no problems, I got it.  The next time, will beeing this advice. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't appear to be with your database, but your use of methods in your code. The server appears to have strict PHP error reporting on, so it is warning you that you've extended methods in your models and other classes that aren't using the same declaration. You need to check each of the methods being warned about and check that you are extending correctly (for example make sure you are defining the correct number/type of parameters for the methods).

Comment: It's a system legacy that I have inheritanced to a older developer...There is working so pretty into the external server..the issue happends only when I try import its to my localhost.